# Undo changes on Git not commited without erase the files - I added my computer files by mistake, and I need to reverse it

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I was studying Git and I did a big mistake that I need to reverse without destroying my system.

I added a lot of system files to my "changes" as you can see in the image below:

[image: Image from Visual Studio Code with the list of added files]

Also this file is part of the `git status` command:

[image: Git status of the files]

I want to revert it without erase the files. I did it once and it changed the full configuration of the system and all the time I open Visual Studio Code it appears to me to commit the changes again.

How can I fix this?

**+More information: I tried these commands already:**

```
 git checkout -f
 fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

 git stash
 You do not have the initial commit yet

 git reflog
 fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet
```

Comment: Did you see the command suggested in the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can do this with `git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git reset
```

This will tell Git to un-add all the files you added, but it won't change or delete any files.

**DO NOT RUN `git reset --hard`**. Git reset --hard will discard all of the files you added, which means it'll delete a bunch of stuff.

Side note: it looks like you made a Git repository in your home directory by accident. If you prefer, you can just delete the hidden `.git` folder inside your home directory. This get rid of the Git repository without affecting anything else.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I was afraid to take any step again. I did the "Side note" action you suggested and then just to check I executed: git status and it doesn't appear nothing more. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!